# Doctrine OneToOne with multiple tables

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, dql, zend-framework3

Im using doctrine 2 and zend framework 3. I got  an entity "Project" with an OneToOne Relation to "projectdetails". ProjectDetails is split between multiple tables depending on a the Project field "type".

Is there an easy way to tell doctrine which table to use for the projectdetails depending on the type field Value?

Comment: Why not save the details on project entity is there any specific reason to have OneToOne relation ?

Comment: The details are fixed information from an external source with multiple sources and i need 1 table for each source. They can change within a project but i need to be able to compare the information from the details object with the information from the project itself.

Answer (score 3):

You can define "OneToOne" associations for each of the projectdetails tables:

```
/**
 * @OneToOne(targetEntity="ProjectDetails1")
 * @JoinColumn(name="project_details_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $projectDetails1;

/**
 * @OneToOne(targetEntity="ProjectDetails2")
 * @JoinColumn(name="project_details_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 */
private $projectDetails2;
```

Add any more projectdetails tables.
Then use a getter function to get the correct relation based on type:

```
function getProjectDetails() {
    if($this->type === 'type1') {
        return $this->projectDetails1;
    }
    elseif($this->type === 'type2') {
        return $this->projectDetails2;
    }
}
```

***Update***: In this case you cannot use doctrine console tool to generate your associations, as it will be impossible to set the foreign key on "project_details_id" to 2 different tables.

To solve this, the column **project_details_id** of integer type should be created with a migration or you can define a field in the Project entity:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer", nullable=true)
 */
private $projectDetailsId;
```

generate & run the migration. Finally replace the latter field with the above associations.

Comment: That would Do, Thanks. But is there a way around creating a subclass for every projectdetails type? Its always the Same entity just a different table.

Comment: @Jannes Botis! What happens in schema if you run doctrine:migrations:migrate? I assume project_id is PK in projects table and also PK/FK both for ProjectDetails1 and ProjectDetails2. If You run mentioned command ,  I see unique key issue. I want to know, if there is something at your end.

Comment: Unfortunately, in this case you cannot use the doctrine console tool to make your schema updates, generating and running migrations. To overcome this, you can initially define a integer field with no association, generate & run your migration and afterwards use the above associations. I will update my answer to make it more clear.

Comment: @Sam Note I updated the name from "project_id" to "project_details_id".